# AngularJS - jQuery - Templates

Tags: jquery, angularjs, search

Can jQuery and AngularJS be used together? I'm asking because I've built an AngularJS search app and I'm having trouble having 2 unique templates. I know that sounds strange with an SPA but I wanted 2 unique templates, one for the hp and the other for the results page. The transition from query page to results page is breaking `$scope` in Angular, using UI Router. I did have it working but it was very simple, once you add autocomplete/search functionality, it breaks.

So now I'm looking at a jQuery plugin for autocomplete on the homepage, which on search submission will go to the AngularJS results page - which I guess is how I need to handle this.

How would I connect the search query from jQuery to AngularJS?

OR

Is there a way to transition from state to state when someone presses on a key on the query page and it goes to the results page, where autocomplete and search can then commence?

Comment: Yea, I kind of asked this out of frustration, I've done some research and am in a better way now. Just close it out or delete it - whichever

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes, you can use jQuery with Angular. But its not a best practice.

To help you more, please provide some code examples.